# HTTPS in development environment

Tags: reactjs

I use letsencrypt certificate on my server. When running my app with  `HTTPS=true npm start` command, I have an error when browsing my app.

> SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket
>   connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.

Here is my config:
in package.json

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
"prestart": "(cat /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainxxx/cert.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainxxx/privkey.pem > ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/ssl/server.pem) || :",
```

(running on debian 9 server)

Comment: So why you use `ws://` instead of `wss://`? Does your websocket server support SSL encryption?

Comment: I don't know if I'm right, but I changed it in node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js  file.

Comment: You are not supposed to edit anything inside `node_modules`. We can't help you without seeing your code.